# Python/PyCharm: Differences when running subpackage modules

Tags: python, module, pycharm, python-import

I have a project subdivided into packages, in the following structure:

```
/project
    /pkg
        __init__.py
        engine.y
        ai.py
    __init__.py
    test_script.py
```

engine.py has an import statement to use ai.py which looks like

```
import pkg.ai as ai
```

This means that test_script.py can be run in the command line as `python test_script.py` and it has no issues. However for debugging purposes, engine.py is also often run. When running in PyCharm it has no problems but when using `python engine.py` I get errors saying `No module named pkg`.

Is there any way I can run engine.py in the command line so that it does not have import errors the way PyCharm does it?

Interestingly the way PyCharm works is that if I do not put that `pkg.` in front of the import module, it underlines it in red saying it can't find the module (but still runs). I've looked everywhere for a solution to this but have only got more confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best explanation to this issue was explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14132912/7344150). In short, keep the absolute imports with `import pkg.ai` in engine.py but when I want to run the engine module for testing reasons it should be run on the top level (when in project dir) with the module flag, such as:

```
cd project/
python -m pkg.engine
```

Comment: Besides your answer, that link you researched is great.

Answer (score 0):

Make something similar to what you've done with `test_script.py` In the same script or in another one in the same level and invoke the scripts from there.

You may also want to read my two answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47499730/a-clean-way-to-organize-and-load-files-with-subclasses/47501913#47501913) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49033015/how-can-i-access-sibling-packages-in-a-maintainable-and-readable-way/49089630#49089630), they contain two examples on how to use import packages. That should help you understand their usage.

Comment: Thanks for this, certainly helped with researching the answer