# How to import module in different path without appending path to module?

Tags: python, import

Given below repo structure

```
cli_stats/      
|__ __init__.py 
|__ README.md   
|__ docs/   
|     |__ docs
|__ cli_stats/  
|     |__  cli_stats.py
|     |__  league_season_init.pickle (generated from setup.py)
|__ pickle/ 
|     |__  __init__.py
|     |__  setup.py
|     |__  get_id/
|     |       |__ __init__.py
|     |       |__ get_id.py
|     |__ get_stats/
|     |       |__ __init__.py
|     |       |__ get_stats.py
|     |__ api_scraper/
|         |__ __init__.py
|         |__ api_scraper.py
|         |__  check_api.py
|       
|__ directory/  
|    |__ __init__.py
|    |__ directory.py
|__clean_stats/ 
     |__ __init__.py
     |__ clean_stats.py
```

How can I import for example import `directory.py` to `clean_stats.py` without inserting the path to `directory.py` to `clean_stats.py` directly? What I'm doing now:

```py
sys.path.insert(0, '../directory')
from directory import Directory
```

What I would like to do:

```py
from directory import Directory
```

Is there someway to utilise the `__init__.py` to be able to do these kind of imports?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `clean_stats.py`:

`from ..directory import Directory`

For `Directory` to be recognized, instead of having to write

`from ..directory.directory import Directory` you will need to put
in `directory/__init__.py`:

`from . import Directory`

Finally, all relative imports work fine when you import your package from one upper level, that is, from a script in the parent folder of `cli_stats`.

If you start execution from some other entry point inside your package, there are always imports that will fail, unless you fix the relative path from the point of view of the starting script. Problem is, if you do that, you fix one place and others will become wrong, always. So make your import package to be imported and used from outside, not to run directly from an inside script. Even if you write absolute import paths starting with the package name everywhere, this issue persists because the inner starting point cannot see the outer subpackages.

Note that there are other options like appending `sys.path` as you did, defining `PYTHONPATH`, or having packages installed in the system or in a virtualenv via `pip`, `pip -e` and so on. But all this options are usually for additional libraries you depend on, not for your package internals.

Comment: Thank you for the input! Every time I have been running a module I have been standing in the working directory, if I understand correctly I should be standing in `cli_stats` when executing a module given that I fix all the import statements?

Comment: A module is the same as a `.py` file or a Python script. Every time you put an `__init__.py` inside a folder you turn that folder into a (regular import) package. A package can have any number of subpackages in the same way (this usually organizes a package internal code consisiting of maybe many modules). An import package is made to be imported by external code, just like the imports you do in your modules from the standard library.

Comment: So, no you should not be in the working dir of the module. Modules using the package should be using the package from, well anywhere, given this is outside the package, and given the package can be found.

Comment: A simple answer is to put the package folder in the same folder of the modules that import it.

Comment: This works because the working (execution) folder is part of the Python search path for modules and packages.

Comment: But the package can be anywhere else. Just add its path to `sys.path` for example. Do this in the modules that need to import the package.

Comment: To answer your question, no you should be in the `cli_stats` parent folder. Do not confuse the regulat import package structure with any additional folder structure that may be used to make a package distribution, which is a different thing that requires the setup.py and so on. You don't need that for your own use. Only for distributing the package to others, or to be able to install it for yourself like if it was third party package (pip installs and such...)

Comment: @MisterButter just to be sure you are notified, because I'm commenting my answer not the question.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is very much information to digest, and I'm trying to wrap my head around everything. The trouble I'm having is understanding the optimal configuration given a structure and how to package all the modules "correctly"

Comment: As of now almost all the modules use `sys.path.insert(0, '../someDirectory')` to be able to import them

Comment: For modules inside a package to work with each other, you definitely don't need that. Only if you want the package internal code to access another external package.